do-release-upgrade not upgrading kernel
Just upgraded a desktop workstation "do-release-upgrade" from 18.04.06 LTS to 20.04. Seems OK, except the kernel is stuck on 5.4.0-182-generic - NOT 5.15.0-107-generic as on all other 20.04 boxes - and system reports (inxi) 20.04 LTS - not 20.04.6 LTS.  Suggestions welcomed.
Many tnx. Paul
Fixed:  thanks to all for your recommendations, they worked, but there was one additional step:
sudo apt install dash
/.../ The following package was automatically installed and is no   longer required: 
distro-info
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg
/.../ The following packages will be REMOVED:
libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dash dpkg
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 


It appears your kernel is being installed using the linux-generic series of packages. 5.4.0-182 is the latest version in that series as of this writing for 20.04. Install the linux-generic-hwe-20.04 series to get the 5.15 kernels, and when that is booted into and working, remove the linux-generic series.
On my 20.04 box the packages are
linux-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04

but other systems may have additional packages (tools,etc). Check which linux-generic packages you have installed.
See How to stop updating of non-HWE kernels after installing HWE kernels in Ubuntu LTS releases? (written for 16.04 but still applies) for the latter part.

Many thanks. I now have kernel 5.15.0-107-generic -- note no mention of hwe, but apt reports:

apt reports:
linux-generic-hwe-20.04 is already the newest version (5.15.0.107.117~20.04.1)
and Unable to locate package linux-generic-20.04

And I still do not have the minor version of the LTS release:
paul@anotherbox:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Check the version of the package base-files and see if that can be updated. Mine is version 11ubuntu5.8 from the focal-updates repo. You do have that repo enabled, right?

What were you running? GA or HWE kernel on 18.04?
For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the 5.4 is the GA kernel stack, with 5.15 the HWE kernel only.
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop installed with either the GA or HWE kernel stack depending on media used (you didn't specify), and when you release-upgrade to 20.04, your original 18.04 settings are honored & that kernel stack kept.
If your 18.04 install used 18.04 or 18.04.1 media; the GA kernel stack was used; if you used 18.04.2 or later media, you opted to use the HWE kernel stack. This applied to flavors of Ubuntu, plus prior LTS releases too. Your install media sets the kernel stack in use.
